# If a command on a MVC page does not navigate to a new view shouldnt I always use jquery ajax posts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was thinking... I am used to doing the classic MVC style of using Url.Actions to call methods and then return a view (even the same view) with a view model.

But then as I thought about jquery and AJAX I thought.. .if the page (view)does not change shouldn't I always use jquery ajax for my commands???

For examples I have a MVC application that you click a button and calls a Url.Action method which performs a long running method.. so from the user point of view the browser hangs for about a minute... But if I used jquery ajax I could call that method... have it return immediately and then I could perhaps set up a timer that calls another method to show progress of this long running process...

So is my theory correct? ALWAYS use jquery ajax for methods that return the same page. ALWAYS use Url.Action for methods that return a new page.

Comment: I disagree. There are plenty of valid reasons an action would return the same view as the previous request.

Comment: "Always" is a loaded word.  The only thing you should "always" do is determine the best course of action in each individual case and tailor the code to match that case.

Comment: ok.. Can anyone say why using jquery ajax instead of Url.action when not navigating to a new page is a BAD IDEA?

Comment: ok. I can understand that example.. though for my project it is all internal so there is none of that.. so still seems like I have nothing to lose using ajax over url.action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, there is NEVER going to be a practice that you will ALWAYS use in a given scenario, and trying to define one will inevitably create bad habits and you will never become a better developer. Things change from project to project, and requirement to requirement. If the page needs to make a server call and not refresh, use ajax. if it needs to refresh or redirect, use a url.action. to clarify, ajax is asynchronous javascript and xml. the main purpose of ajax is to make server calls asynchronous so that there is no locking in the browser. this allows you to execute other logic while your server call is happening and awaiting results. it will also allow you to not refresh/redirect upon submitting a form to your server. this can be very helpful in some cases but in others, maybe not so much.

Scope: i am a .net developer working in mvc4 so i have alot of experience with this particular question. We make very large scale asp.net applications and use this concept widely. We use ajax thousands of times throughout our applications but there are always certain cases where we still use the default web forms model to send data to a server side script via a method.

Comment: ok... so it sounds like there is nothing negative using a ajax call rather than a Url.Action when not changing pages.. ?  I know there is no 100% but I want to switch some of my calls to ajax since it always me the bonus of return control right back to the client which seems to me only a good thing ?

Comment: any time that you are sending very sensitive information to your server ie. login information, credit card information, or any other personal information. You don't want to send this type of information via ajax because the data that is being sent is visible in your source code and can be accessed/hijacked. with url.action the data is not as easily acessible